# Confused about list variable assignment

Tags: python, list, variables

I'm following a book and i ran into this sample program. I'm not sure how the `numbers[position]` in line 5 is working here? What is the relationship between `position` and `numbers` in that variable assignment?

```
numbers = [1, 3, 5]
position = 0

while position < len(numbers):
    number = numbers[position]
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print "Found even number", number
        break
    position = position + 1

else:
    print "No even number found"
```

Comment: Do you mean this line : `number = numbers[position]` ?

Comment: If this book uses list indexing syntax before explaining what list indexing syntax is, and manually increments a number from 0 to len(numbers) in a while loop instead of doing `for position in range(len(numbers)):` or just `for number in numbers:`, then I think you should find a better book.

Comment: Add some print statements and watch them change.

Comment: @Kevin: Agreed. I hate how books focus on C-like `range(len(someseq))` loops with indexing in the loop, thereby teaching new Python programmers the least Pythonic way to accomplish iterable iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That number inside square brackets is an index of the list,

like so

```
lst = ["b", "c", 3] # Take care not to use "list" as a variable name by the way.
print lst[0]        # I used lst in my example
```

gives you:

```
"b"
```

The first element of the list.

However I could not pass without saying that for loop is a far better way of doing this. Rather than incrementing position one-by-one and telling while loop to stop when it reaches to the length of the list is just good for understanding the concepts. I am sure your textbook is going to cover that next.

Comment: Note that in Python (and several other languages) lists/arrays are indexed starting from 0, rather than starting from 1.

Comment: Yea, tried to indicate that by showing but i guess it was confusing with comment marks. Thanks kadrian

Comment: Now it should be `print lst[0]`

Answer (score 0):

It's not variable assignment, it's lookup. `position` is an index; when it has a value of `0`, `numbers[position]` returns `1` (the first element in `numbers`), for `position` `1` it gets `3`, etc.

Python sequences like `list` are indexed 0-up, so the first element in a sequence is at index `0`, and the last is at index `len(seq) - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

In `number = numbers[position]` literally means what it says. `position` is a position in the list. First it is assigned to zero, so when doing `numbers[position]` it is actually calling the number in the list at position zero which is 1. Then it does `position = position + 1` which will ask it for the number in position 1 in the list and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't familiar with this style of variable assignment. I've seen lists referenced directly using index numbers. But since this post, I've tried the following and it cleared it up. Thank you very much!

```
list1 = ["apples", "oranges"]
position = 1

output1 = list1[0]
output2 = list1[position]

print output1
print output2
```